# Unable to use Performance Plugin with Hudson

Tags: maven-2, jmeter, hudson-plugins

I have been trying to integrate JMeter test with Maven and Hudson. I came across [this](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2008/03/automated-performance-tests-using.html) beautiful post on Maven JMeter and got it set up easily.
And then I got to know that Hudson has a [performance plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Performance+Plugin) using with JMeter results could be directly displayed on Hudson dashboard. 
Now problem I face is in using Performance plugin of Hudson. 
Performance plugin says to specify path of JMeter Report files wherein default path is considered as "**/*.jtl" if no path is specified.
My Maven JMeter tests produce this file under "target\jmeter-reports\GoogleAdvanceSearch.xml" 
Notice that an "xml" file is generated here but it is same as ".jtl" file.
I provided the entire path this xml file under "report files" section of Hudson but when ever I initiate a build I encounter following exception after performance test execution -

```
Performance: Recording JMeter reports 'C:\SelNG\jmeter2\target\jmeter-reports\GoogleAdvanceSearch-100905.xml'
Performance: no JMeter files matching 'C:\SelNG\jmeter2\target\jmeter-reports  \GoogleAdvanceSearch-100905.xml' have been found. Has the report generated?. Setting Build to FAILURE
```

But  I know that file is physically available at the location I specified.

To double check if problem is coz of "xml" file and not having ".jtl" file as specified in performance plugin of Hudson. Now I created a build file which would execute JMeter tests and generate ".jtl" file. Now get to see following ".jtl" file generated. "C:\SelNG\jmeter\GoogleSearch.jtl". I specified this path under "Performance Report > Report files" section of Hudson plugin but again encountered same exception on build execution

```
Performance: Recording JMeter reports 'C:\SelNG\jmeter\GoogleSearch.jtl'
Performance: no JMeter files matching 'C:\SelNG\jmeter\GoogleSearch.jtl' have been     found. Has the report generated?. Setting Build to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Though I know that file 'C:\SelNG\jmeter\GoogleSearch.jtl' is physically available at specified location.

What is that I am missing in here? has any one of u come across such problem while using Hudson-Performance plugin?

Thanks in advance
~ T

Comment: well, have I written it too complicated to understand? or is it really silly to answer?

Comment: Well some success but not satisfying enough. First I should be using forward "/". Hence path to report which I need to specify is - "C:/SelNG/jmeter2/target/jmeter-reports/GoogleAdvanceSearch-100906.xml" but the problem here is the time stamp attached with report, hence I tried to use Regular expression as specified in Hudson-JMeter plugin doc - "**/*.xml" but with this I encounter following exception - *******************************Performance: 
Performance: no JMeter files matching '**/*.xml' have been found. Has the report generated?. Setting Build to FAILURE*****

Comment: What's odd, is in the first example, there is extra white space in the file name in  "jmeter-reports    ".    Are you sure the regex is correct for grabbing the date? I think the way you have it written, it would be looking for xml files in the default path, rather then in your jmeter-reports folder.

Comment: Thanks Black.... u r right, report is in jmeter-reports folder... The absolute path is - "C:\SelNG\jmeter2\target\jmeter-reports\Jagran-100908.xml"...  If I specify the entire path under "Report files" for Hudson it works... but since xml file has time attached to it I can't provide this path.. so I tried using "**/*.xml"... but it does not work and I encounter failure... Is there some thing wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you a little.
Hudson select job. Choose configure.

Let's focus on paths

This is my path to tests
    c:\Hudson\data\jobs\template-peformance-test2-mvn\workspace\trunk\src\test\jmeter\

This is my path to report files

```
c:\Hudson\data\jobs\template-peformance-test2-mvn\workspace\trunk\target\jmeter-reports\
```

For Hudson the root starts in job workspace.

My Build conf:

```
Root POM: trunk\pom.xml
Goals and options: celan verify
```

Then in Post Build Actions

selected Publish Performance test result report

Performance report JMeter

```
Report files */target/jmeter-reports/*.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I am not using it any more. I hope it helps others.